# Use Reference Variable

Tags: java, variables

I have two class ,following:

first Class:

```
package MemoryInterfaces;

import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 *
 * @author omid
*/
public class MemoryData<T> {

private Object _datas =null;

public MemoryData() {
}

/**
 * @return the _data
 */
public SortedSet<T> getDatas() {
  if (this._datas==null) {
     this._datas=new TreeSet<T>();
     getDataOfDatabase();
  }

  return (SortedSet<T>)_datas;
}

/**
 * @param data the _data to set
 */
public void setDatas(SortedSet<T> datas) {
    this._datas=datas;
}

public T getDataOfMemory(int i) {
  return (T) getDatas().toArray()[i];
}

public void addItem(T data) {
  this.getDatas().add(data);
}

public void remove(T data) {
  this.getDatas().remove(data);
}

protected void getDataOfDatabase() {
}
}
```

second Class:

```
public class CabinetImpl extends MemoryData<CabinetItem> {

private static SortedSet<CabinetItem> _datas = null;

public CabinetImpl() {
   setDatas(_datas);
}

@Override
protected void getDataOfDatabase() {
  CabinetDaoImpl _cab = new CabinetDaoImpl();
  List<Cabinet> _lst = _cab.getTable();

  if (!_lst.isEmpty()) {

     for (int i = 0; i < _lst.size(); i++) {
       AddToMemory(_lst.get(i).getID(), _lst.get(i).getName(), _lst.get(i).getSub(), _lst.get(i).getDepid());
     }
     _datas=getDatas();
  }
}

private void AddToMemory(int id, String name, int sub, int depid) {
  CabinetItem _cab = new CabinetItem(id, name, sub, depid);

  addItem(_cab);
}
}
```

in second Class ,I have a static varible(_datas) be when constructing of cabinetImpl class,_datas transfer to MemoryData but not effect changes in MemoryData on _datas.

Please Help Me!

Comment: I suggest you are a specific question.

Comment: This strongly suggests you are using the wrong collection. `return (T) getDatas().toArray()[i];`

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to override a private variable of a super class in an inherited class. Use the getters and setters of MemoryData

Answer (score 0):

You have two different fields with the same name in different classes.

They are no relationship to each other and different types.  If you want to have only one copy I suggest removing one of them.